# setting Css attribute on server control

Tags: css, properties, controls

I am creating a server control that contains a textbox, image and several other controls.  I am setting the attributes of the various embedded controls using properties.  Is there a way to do this using Css?

Example Code for Server Control:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomControlLibrary
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:InputBox runat=server></{0}:InputBox>")]
    public class InputBox : Control
    {

        [
        Category("Custom Properties"),
        Description("Sets the width for the textbox."),
        DefaultValue("175px")
        ]
        public string TextboxWidth { get; set; }


    ...code to render controls...

     }
}
```

I can do this:

```
<cc1:InputBox ID="InputBox1" runat="server" 
    TextboxWidth="25px">
</cc1:InputBox>
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
.tb
{
TextboxWidth:"25px";
}

        <cc1:InputBox ID="InputBox1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="tb">
        </cc1:InputBox>
```

I have searched and searched and searched and cannot find anything so perhaps this isn't possible but if anyone has any ideas please share.

Thank you,
Greg